# Reading struct7 from file

Tags: c, file, data-structures

I tried to write some structures into a txt file and it worked.Now I want to put the content of the file inside the same struct but I cant put it because it reads only the first row and the first element of the second. Please help me!

This is the code:

```
r = fopen("user1.txt","r");

while(fread(&d[i], sizeof(struct date), 1, r))
   {
    printf ("%s %s %s %s %s %s \n", d[i].f.email,d[i].f.parola,d[i].nume,d[i].prenume,d[i].adresa,d[i].varsta);
    i+=1;
   }
```

The text file looks like that: [the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deV71.png)

When I print the content into the code it looks like this (the content in the red circle) :

The struct code :

```
struct logare{

    char email[100];
    char parola[100];
    
    }A[100];
    struct date
    {
     struct logare f;
     char nume[100];
     char prenume[100];
     char adresa[100];
     char varsta[3];
    
    }d[100];
```

Comment: You should use `"rb"` instead of `"r"` to read binary files.

Comment: nothing happened....the same output.btw,it`s not a binary file

Comment: You can't "read" text as a structure, make sure you write to a binary file when you want to save your structures then read binary from that file

Comment: So I only change from "r" to "rb " and "w" to "wb"?

Comment: @GrigoriRasputin yes, and dont write text from strucutre, write the structure instead

Comment: @Grigori Rasputin - _When I print the content …_ - the content of what? It can't be the content from the file, since you say _it reads only the first row and the first element of the secound._